# Filtered table returns to its unfiltered state whenever I change routes and go back to that component

Tags: angular, angular6

I made a table that has filter and pagination in it. It is working, however, whenever I change routes and go back to that component It returns to its unfiltered form. I'm aware on how it happens, because I declare the code in ngOnInit method. Is there any way for it to stay to its filtered form whenever I change routes and get back to the previous component? I declare it to ngOnInit method because it should be displayed initially. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **[`Shared Service`](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)** and keep the data filtered in the service. A service in Angular is a singleton, meaning it is managed as a single instance. So you can access the same data from various componennts even after you navigate.